# Sybase select value from XML field

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sybase

I have a table named data_values stored in SYBASE in the following format:

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | value
```

The value field has the following XML format:

```
<T key1=value1 key2=value2 .... keyn=valuen /T>
```

I want to select from the value field values like value1, value2, etc. but I can't find a correct query to do this.

I have tried:

```
SELECT value.value('(/T//value1/node())[1]', 'varchar(255)') as value1 from data_values
```

also value is a reserved keyword I think and I need to escape it somehow.
Other things I have tried is a value.query function which didn't work in Sybase.
Also, I am pretty new to Sybase and didn't work a lot with complex sql queries.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version are you using? if `ASE`, you might want to check the manual [XML Services](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE?locale=en-US)

Comment: Write the parse login in the middleware layer, that would be the easier solution.

Comment: It's Sybase ASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a tag in Sybase ASE the following xmlextract function can be used:

e.g for key1 and value1 :

```
select xmlextract('/T/@key1', value returns <DATATYPE>) as value1 from data_values
```

Where   is the type of the data you want to return ( INT, FLOAT, VARCHAR, ETC) and value is the name of the XML column.